# AForge ShapeCheker.IsCircle method

Tags: c#, aforge

well i'm using SimpleShapeChecker.IsCircle method to detect my pupil. It work really fine, but when i look to the sides the pupil turns like an oval/ellipse shape. Is there a method to detect ovals?, or is there a way to "relax" IsCircle() method?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Unfurtunately in AForge there is not IsOval() function.

But you can take a look at the source code of the shape checker!

https://code.google.com/p/aforge/source/browse/trunk/Sources/Math/Geometry/SimpleShapeChecker.cs?r=1402

You can see the IsCircle() function and modify it to see if is oval or not.

This is the function:

```
public bool IsCircle( List<IntPoint> edgePoints, out Point center, out float radius )
        {
            // make sure we have at least 8 points for curcle shape
            if ( edgePoints.Count < 8 )
            {
                center = new Point( 0, 0 );
                radius = 0;
                return false;
            }

            // get bounding rectangle of the points list
            IntPoint minXY, maxXY;
            PointsCloud.GetBoundingRectangle( edgePoints, out minXY, out maxXY );
            // get cloud's size
            IntPoint cloudSize = maxXY - minXY;
            // calculate center point
            center = minXY + (Point) cloudSize / 2;

            radius = ( (float) cloudSize.X + cloudSize.Y ) / 4;

            // calculate mean distance between provided edge points and estimated circle’s edge
            float meanDistance = 0;

            for ( int i = 0, n = edgePoints.Count; i < n; i++ )
            {
                meanDistance += (float) Math.Abs( center.DistanceTo( edgePoints[i] ) - radius );
            }
            meanDistance /= edgePoints.Count;

            float maxDitance = Math.Max( minAcceptableDistortion,
                ( (float) cloudSize.X + cloudSize.Y ) / 2 * relativeDistortionLimit );

            return ( meanDistance <= maxDitance );
        }
```

Maybe if you play with the minAcceptableDistortion variable, you can detect ovals too!

Hope it helped.